# MySQL не передает данные из запроса

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

MySQL при переносе не хочет передавать данные, иногда переносит, иногда нет! Соединение с phpmyadmin работает нормально.

Подключение

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

function createConnection() {
  return mysql.createConnection({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: config.host,
    user: config.user,
    database: config.database,
    password: config.password,
  });
}

function createConnection2() {
  return mysql.createConnection({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: config.host,
    user: config.usertwo,
    database: config.database,
    password: config.passtwo,
  });
}

function connectToDatabase(createConnection) {
  const connection = createConnection();

  connection.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error connecting to database:', err);
      setTimeout(connectToDatabase, 2000);
    } else {
      console.log('Database connected');
    }
  });
  connection.on('error', err => {
    console.error('Database connection error:', err);
    if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
      connectToDatabase();
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  });

  return connection;
}

const conn = connectToDatabase(createConnection);
const conn2 = connectToDatabase(createConnection2);
```

Запрос

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  conn.query(`SELECT * FROM ${type} WHERE ${search} = ?`, [userid], (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      if (results.length > 0) {
        resolve(results[0]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I don’t know what needs to be done on VDS hosting to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Please translate your question into Russian or use [Stack Overflow in English](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: MySQL при переносе не хочет передавать данные, иногда переносит, иногда нет! Соединение с phpmyadmin работает нормально.

Comment: Не, вам нужно отредактировать вопрос (кнопка "Править"), перевести как заголовок, так и тело вопроса.

Comment: Сделал, так я сам Русский думал то что по Англ мне помогут быстрее